# How to add watermark into an image stored in S3 bucket using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-s3, watermark, bucket

I don't want to download images to the local, and I want add logo as watermark in image, that images stored in S3 bucket.

I do not want do this watermark process in local system, I don't know how to do this. This is my code in CodeIgniter

```
public function GetRendomImgForMaxico()
    {
        /* S3 server :- get 5 order and one image from each orders */
         $getRendomLatestOrder = $this->db->query("select invoice from ord_order
            left join users
            on users.id = ord_order.userId and users.region_id < 36
            where ord_order.payment_status = 'P' AND ord_order.num_day_shoots > 0
            order by ord_order.id desc limit 5");
        $latestImgs = $getRendomLatestOrder->result_array();

        $this->load->library('aws_sdk');
        foreach ($latestImgs as $latestImg) {
            $response = $this->aws_sdk->listObjects(
                array(
                    'Bucket' => $this->bucket_name, 
                    'MaxKeys' => 1000, 
                    'Prefix' => $this->order_directory.'ORD_'.$latestImg['invoice'].'/MLS/'
                )
            );
            $image = $response->getPath('Contents');
            $images[] = end($image);
        }
        $urls = array_column($images, 'Key');
        foreach($urls as $key=>$url) {
            $urls[$key] = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKETNAME/'.$url;
            $result = $this->aws_sdk->copyObject([
                'Bucket' => $this->config->item('bucketname'),
                'CopySource' => "/".$this->config->item('bucketname')."/".$url,
                'Key' => 'recent_shoots/'.$url,
                'ACL' => 'public-read']
            )->toArray();

            /** Watermark add from here */
            $masterURL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKETNAME/recent_shoots/'.$url;
            $path='https://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKETNAME/recent_shoots/logo/logo.png';
            $this->load->library('image_lib');              
            $config1['image_library'] = 'gd2'; 
            $config1['source_image']     = $masterURL;
            $config1['wm_type']          = 'overlay';
            $config1['wm_overlay_path']  = $path; 
            $config1['wm_opacity']       = 100;
            $config1['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'top';
            $config1['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'right';
            $this->image_lib->initialize($config1);
            $this->image_lib->watermark();
            die();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This process will be handled when you are storing image over the S3. after adding watermark store that image in S3. S3 is platform to store only you can do anything else with it.

Comment: Can you please explain, how can i add watermark on image. ?  after copy image to another folder in bucket. i want to do this